# Upload files bigger than 2Mo Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to upload files bigger than 2Mo and I have this error on my form

```
The file is too large. Allowed maximum size is 2 MiB.
```

This is my model

```
/**
 * @var UploadedFile
 *
 * @Assert\File(maxSize = "32768k")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
protected $file;
```

and in my php.ini

```
post_max_size = 50M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

And I have restarted apache

Answer (score 12, accepted):

most possible apache uses another php than the one you edit the ini

just `phpinfo();`

at the AppKernel.php or app.php

and look for the directory of the correct ini

in example

```
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini
```

Comment: This thing had me running out of my mind. I run `php --ini` on the terminal, edited the config file that was pointed to, but it still didn't work. Tried editing other php.ini files that I came across on my system, to no avail. But this finally worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Praise be! Thank you for posting this.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set your custom values in the .htaccess file at the root of your web/ directory:

```
# File size settings for uploads
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
```